# Select Strings from Windows events via XML

Tags: powershell

I am trying to select property from events I am able to create with script

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='Security'; ID=4728; } -MaxEvents 1 
$event = $events
[xml]$eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()
$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data
```

if I run this it outputs, I need to select targetname,targetusername,subjectusername, I am not able to get the output, anyhelp will be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is the screenshot the output you receive (what's wrong with it?), or the output you desire (what do you actually get?)

Answer (score 2):

As [Swonkie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48356612/1630171) already pointed out, `Data` is an array, and the values you're looking for are actually XML nodes in that array, hence you can't easily select them like you would with the properties of an object.

I would probably create a hashtable for each `Data` array, filter the array for the nodes you want selected, then build a custom object from each hashtable.

```
$names = 'TargetName', 'TargetUserName', 'SubjectUserName'

$events | ForEach-Object {
    ([xml]$_.ToXml()).Event.EventData | ForEach-Object {
        $props = @{}

        $_.Data |
            Where-Object { $names -contains $_.Name } |
            ForEach-Object { $props[$_.Name] = $_.'#text' }

        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
    }
}
```

Comment: cool I changed to 

`$names = 'memberName', 'TargetUserName', 'SubjectUserName'`

Answer (score 0):

`$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data` is an array.

```
$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data | where { $_.Name -eq 'SubjectUserName' } | select -ExpandProperty '#text'
```

Or for PowerShell 3 and up:

```
$eventXML.Event.EventData.Data | where Name -eq 'SubjectUserName' | select -ExpandProperty '#text'
```